# QBFC having trouble connecting to QuickBooks running under Citrix

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

We have a client that has installed our app in a Citrix environment on their server. Sometimes QuickBooks will connect and other times it gets the following error in qbsdklog.txt

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    ========= Started Connection =========

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v13.0

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Connection opened by app named 'Well Profits - SherWare, Inc.'

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Current User is in AdminGroup

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Current Process Integrity Level : 2000
20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Previous instance of QB is going down..! Wait and retry to get a new instance.

20171212.145407 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Previous instance of QB is going down..! Wait and retry to get a new instance.

20171212.145408 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Previous instance of QB is going down..! Wait and retry to get a new instance.

20171212.145408 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Previous instance of QB is going down..! Wait and retry to get a new instance.

20171212.145409 I   15312   RequestProcessor    Previous instance of QB is going down..! Wait and retry to get a new instance.

20171212.145409 E   15312   RequestProcessor    Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder

QuickBooks is already running and has the QuickBooks company open.

Anybody have success running consistently under Citrix?

Comment: Yes, we've deployed to Citrix and MS Terminal Servers successfully.  Are you running either app in Administrator mode?

Comment: Neither are running in Administrator mode. What's strange is that it works for a while and then quits.

Comment: Not sure.... Be sure QB option (in prefs) to keep QB open in the background for faster startups is UNCHECKED.  Is QB returning an error?  Also, are you specifying a company file in your BeginSession command?  If so, try without.  [See this for similar issue.](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2529/45/qodbc-desktop-qb-begin-session-failed-error--80040408-could-not-start-quickbooks)